# React Hook Form Controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, html-formhandler

I am using react hook form controller on material UI textField component where the type i am giving as file.

```
<Controller
            name={name}
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
              <ReactHookFormSelector
                selector={selector}
                type={type}
                multiline={multiline}
                value={value}
                onChange={(event) => {
                        console.log(event.target.files)
                        onChange(event.target.files)
                      }
                }
              />
```

Here i want to store this file and value in the redux store state while submitting this form

And i want to use that file and value later in another Textfield(input=file) component.

Can anybody help me how i can store this file and value in redux and use it later?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `react-hooks-form`, you can use `setValue` to the file .

and then use `watch` or `getValues()` functions from the react-hooks-form to access the state in another component.

```
      onChange={(event) => {
        console.log(event.target.files)
         setValue("files",event.target.files[0].name)
         }
       }
```

then use watch :

```
const filesWatch = getValues("files")
```

More in here : `https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform`

Comment: used the setValue, but got this error.

Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: ok but you try this  event.target.files[0] ?

Comment: you can check [this](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/8052#discussioncomment-2393534), try `e.target.files[0].name`

Comment: yes , i edited the code. that depance on what he want to same in the state.